# Getting an output of Prime Number for 15,25,35 even though i know it is not

Tags: c++

If number is like 25,35 output is "This number is prime",even though I know it's not a prime number. Why am I getting that output? With several other casual numbers it works.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isPrimeNumber(int number){
    bool isPrimeFlag=true;
    for(int i=2;i<number;i++){
        if(number % i == 0)
            isPrimeFlag=false;
            break;
    }
    return isPrimeFlag;
}
int main(){
    int number;
    cout<<"Number: ";
    cin>>number;
    bool isPrimeFlag = isPrimeNumber(number);
    if(isPrimeFlag)
        cout<<"Prime Number"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Not Prime Number"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: Indeed. Step through the code in the debugger and you'll find your (quite simple) bug very easily. And then you'll know how to use your debugger.

Comment: This is a perfect example why this coding style is evil

Comment: Curly braces are cheap. Don't be clever to save space. (And use an editor that can indent your code for you.)

Comment: There's a plenty of advices, here's one more: enable your compiler warnings. My compiler tells me `this 'if' clause does not guard this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the 'if'`, with line numbers and everything to find an issue.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Ooooh, I like that. Which compiler is that?

Comment: @Dai clang since 10.x https://godbolt.org/z/77dPT5. I am used to gcc and sometimes I am a bit jealous of clangs messages

Comment: @Dai actually in this case gcc helps as well https://godbolt.org/z/oK93Ys

Comment: @Dai GCC since 6.1 it seems: https://wandbox.org/permlink/5bNnbQCquicKyJsv, and clang was mentioned above. I'm surprised, I would have thought clang had it first.

Comment: BTW, you can skip even numbers after 2, i.e. 4 is not a prime divisor.  Start your loop at 3 and increment by 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
    for(int i=2;i<number;i++){
        if(number % i == 0)
            isPrimeFlag=false;
            break;
    }
```

C++ is not Python: indentation does not affect your program's semantics - what matters are braces, and you have a missing brace for the inner `if` so the `break` instruction is always executed even if the `if( number % i )` statement is `false`.

Whenever writing in C, C++, and other [*easy-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot* languages](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/) it helps to use [a linter tool that will force you to always use braces](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint).

```
    for(int i=2;i<number;i++){
        if(number % i == 0) {
            isPrimeFlag=false;
            break;
        }
    }
```